# Best way to store a table of data and query any column

Tags: java, search, data-structures

So I have a school project on which I have to store a set of data in this format:

TITLE / ARTIST / YEAR / GENRE / POSITION

it's for a playlist program, and it requires some queries like this:

*"Get the music immediately before a music with (title/year/artist)"*

*"Find the first situation where a music with genre X is right after a music with genre Y"*

*"What are the musics that were released in the year with less songs released"*

*"Find the non-duplicate music with the biggest title"*

So the data structure I was thinking to use is a combination of a double linked list ordered by the POSITION along with parallel mappings with different keys (one for each field of the line) and the corresponding values being nodes of the linked list.

This will make the querying for those values quicker.

Is there another data structure that improves the queries above?

Comment: What is the expected number of elements? If it's small, and is just an exercise to write Java code, just use an ArrayList. If it's large, and needs to be something serious, use a database.

Comment: It is guaranteed that the POSITION fits in an integer variable, and it's a unique value.
I also have to implement any data structure used. As in code the structure and its methods

Comment: *"Best way to store a table of data and query any column"* - Why not start with a `interface` which describes the properties and functionality of the data, then back it with a concrete class?  You could the simply store in a `ArrayList` and generate additional indices based on your needs

Comment: I am ignorant to indexing, how would one store the indices?